# position:fixed + float:right, where is the div?

Tags: html, css, position, css-position, fixed

I'm still studying HTML and CSS, perhaps this could be a silly mistake or not.

Look in my HTML, I have the #welcome div, but it disappeared when I set float:right.

http://jsfiddle.net/TkQaU/1/

(Chrome or Firefox)

Thanks!

Comment: #container { margin-left:0; } brings back the welcome div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `float:right;` to this:

```
#topbar .content #welcome {
    position:absolute;
    right:100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/TkQaU/6/

If you want to keep the float, you'll need to give it a margin-right of 100px to make up for the margin-left of the container:

```
#topbar .content #welcome {
    float:right;
    margin-right:100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/TkQaU/4/

Answer (score 5):

The `margin-left:100px` shifted your `#container` to the right, causing 100px of the right side to be invisible. When you set `float:right`, the `.welcome` element moves to the right - where it's invisible.

To solve this issue, add `padding-right:100px` to the `.welcome` element.

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TkQaU/3/**